# Force Users to Login - loop problem

Tags: login

I'm using this code below as a plugin. It seems to work but sometimes it seems to be stuck in a loop.  When I have this plugin running my facebook social sharing doesn't grab the correct page and content for a share post.  I turn off the plugin and facebook share works great.  What am I doing wrong?

```
add_action ('template_redirect', 'protect_whole_site');

function protect_whole_site() {
if ( !is_user_logged_in() &&  !in_array( $GLOBALS['pagenow'], array( 'wp-    login.php', 'wp-register.php' ) ) ) {
        auth_redirect();
    exit;
    }
}
```

thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Facebook grabs your site's content by making an http request just like any other visitor, you're forwarding any attempts to scrape your pages to the login page.

You could try [checking for the Facebook user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626812/how-to-recognize-facebook-user-agent) to let their crawlers through, but anyone could masquerade as the Facebook bot and browse your site without logging in by simply changing their browser's user agent.

Comment: thanks.. but my real issue here is to find the correct/best way to force users to login to the standard wordpress login or any url I may want.   can anyone suggest a way or help me fix this endless loop which ultimately crashes.

Comment: You could try not using Facebook and other sharing code on pages that users have to log in to see.

Comment: again,  I would rather forget about facebook right now and fix this endless loop... any suggestions on this function?  is there a better one that doesn't loop out?

Comment: @ThomEdward what endless loop problem? Describe the steps to reproduce this issue. Your code works fine for me on a vanilla WP install and twentytwelve theme.